# How can one justify Newton's third law?

Tags: ontology, kant, aristotle, philosophy-of-physics

In one sense it is justified by the overall success if Newtonian Mechanics; still, one can ask are there arguments that can justify it from other principles; ie principle that are * a priori* in nature. For example, Kant supplied [one](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-science/#PhyCriPerMetFouNatSci), in his *Metaphysics of Natural Science*; and to which he added the remark:

> “[Newton] by no means dared to prove this law a priori, and therefore appealed rather to experience”

His argument is as follows:

> (i) if all changes of matter are changes of motion;
>
> (ii) if all changes of motion are reciprocal and equal (since one body cannot move closer to/farther away from another body without the second body moving closer to/farther away from the first body and by exactly the same amount); and
>
> (iii) if every change of matter has an external cause (a proposition that was established as the Second Law of Mechanics), then the cause of the change of motion of the one body entails an equal and opposite cause of a change of motion of the other body or, in short, action must be equal to reaction

Is the following argument more basic? In that (ii) is deduced from considerations of symmetry:

> Consider an action: what does this mean? A substance can't act on itself, for how can we say it acts now as opposed to then? To make this concrete, consider a classical electron - its negative charge *doesn't* act on itself - otherwise it wouldn't have any cohesion.
>
> It acts then, on an *other*; and then on *contact*; but by *symmetry*, ie swapping the one substance with the other, the same situation is obtained.
>
> Hence every action has an equal an opposite reaction

Where equal and opposite are not to be understood in quantifiable terms; but in the terms outlined above.

And this argued as an outcome of *action by contact*; and by contact that one is *simultaneous* in place and time with another; and that this relation is *symmetric*.

Comment: Can you make clearer what you mean by "justify"?

Comment: Doesn't the second highlight block apply only when the two participants are interchangeable? -- if they differ in some way, then the swapping could make a difference.

Comment: @virmaoir: I think that would be a useful clarification; but I don't have any useful suggestions right now apart from saying in the concepts of space/time/motion used in *at* that time.

Comment: For example, I'm not interested in a justification by recourse to Noether's theorem as one of the answers below suggested; though of course it's an important result.

Comment: @dave: yes, this is what I mean by symmetry here - interchangeable.

Answer (score 4):

See [Noether's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).

This theorem states that for every symmetry, there must be a corresponding conserved quantity.  It's math.

The universe is symmetric regarding translations in space (if everything were moved three feet to the left, nothing would change).  The conserved quantity for this symmetry is momentum.  Thus, because the universe is symmetric regarding translations, momentum must be conserved.

"For every action, there is a (quantifiably) equal and opposite reaction" is logically equivalent to "momentum is a conserved quantity."

Newton justified his law as a generalization of many observations.  We justify it today because Noether's Theorem says it must be true.

Comment: Correct answer, and cannot upvote this one enough.  As an alternative to wikipedia, there was also a recent video on the PBS Spacetime channel that explains Noether's Theorem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04ERSb06dOg

Answer (score 2):

A. P. French wrote in 1971 in his book "Newtonian Mechanics", page 317 and figure 9-4, that if you consider a gun firing particles analogous to photons at a barrier some distance away, that since the photon-like objects cannot be seen, there is the appearance that Newton's third law does not apply until it is absorbed by the barrier.

Scientifically we say that photons have momentum, and we could measure it anywhere along the path from the gun to the barrier, however the issue is that a photon does not take a quantifiable state until such an absorption occurs.  That is to say, it defers to the philosophical question of "Where are photons between emission and absorption?" (Which does not have a precise philosophical answer in the context of the double-slit experiment).

Answer (score 1):

Kant's argument is incorrect. The following statement is false:

> if all changes of motion are reciprocal and equal (since one body cannot move closer to/farther away from another body without the second body moving closer to/farther away from the first body and by exactly the same amount);

If a body of $1$ $\mathrm{kg}$ interacts (e.g. via a spring, or electromagnetic force) with a body of $2$ $\mathrm{kg}, then the change in velocity of the first body will be double the change of velocity in the second body. Any correct derivation of Newton's third law must certainly involve mass, or otherwise it must only apply to bodies of equal mass.

The argument remains incorrect if we consider two equal bodies, because it confuses change in position with change in motion, and it confuses relative motion with motion with respect to a reference frame. Consider a system of many objects of equal mass in any motion whatsoever, and let $A$ and $B$ be two of the objects The assumption that if $A$ moves some amount relative to $B$, then $B$ must move the opposite of that amount relative to $A$, remains true. However, an arbitrary motion of a system of objects certainly does not satisfy Newton's third law. (If it did, then the law would also be vacuous.)

In order to form a correct argument one must first clearly define terms such as force, mass, position, velocity, acceleration. Newton's third law says that the *forces* are equal and opposite. Neither Kant's argument nor your argument mentions the word force.

Remember that Newton's third law is not just a law about two identical objects. It is a law about two *different* objects interacting in any manner whatsoever. So the symmetry argument does not work either.

In physics we define force as the time derivative of momentum. So if $p_A$ is the momentum of object $A$ and $p_B$ is the momentum of object $B$, then Newton's third law says
$$\frac{dp_A}{dt}=- \frac{dp_B}{dt}$$
We can rewrite this as
$$\frac{dp_A}{dt} + \frac{dp_B}{dt} = 0$$
Or, defining the total momentum $P=p_A+p_B$, the law states $dP/dt=0$. This is conservation of momentum. Conservation of momentum is a consequence of two facts: (1) particles move in trajectories of least action (2) the action is invariant under space translation. (1) is a consequence of quantum mechanics, and (2) is an experimental fact. That conservation of momentum follows from (1) and (2) is called Noether's theorem. You say that "I'm not interested in a justification by recourse to Noether's theorem", but Noether's theorem *is* the justification. You can surely come up with a string of words that tickles some human brains in just the right way as to activate the "I'm convinced by this argument" center, but that string of words will not work on physicists. You can't do physics without doing physics.

Comment: I'm not interested in Noether's theorem as a justification because it doesn't help with justifying it *a priori*; Noether's principle came out of understanding the structure of Mechanics. Have you considered how Newton came up with his laws? They're usually just presented to us as a *fait accompli*.

Comment: IIRC Newton found the law by doing experiments with objects sliding on glass plates.

Comment: Also, the law was to some extent known to Galileo and Huygens.

Comment: They were known in some form to Aristotle too. See Barbours *The Discovery of Dynamics*.

Comment: By the way do you have a reference for these experiments by Newton? I'm tried looking on the net but I can't find anything. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I learned it in a history of physics course but I don't have a reference for it. A problem is that the old physicists did not carefully record their experiments. Here is a work by Huygens in which he establishes the conservation of momentum: http://www.princeton.edu/~hos/Mahoney/texts/huygens/impact/huyimpct.html  As you can see he does not describe experiments, but he does list hypotheses on which he bases his deduction. These hypotheses have to be verified with experiments.

Comment: I looked it up in the Principia, and Newton credits Wren, Wallis, and Huygens for the following experiment. It was known to Galilei that gravity accelerates an object uniformly, so that its speed scales with t^2. Using this it is possible to determine the relation between the maximum speed and the maximum height of a pendulum, thus making it easy to set up and measure velocities.

Comment: We take two pendula of unequal weight barely touching each other at rest. We lift up one pendulum to a known height and let it collide with the other, so that the velocity right before the collision is known. We can determine velocities right after the collision from the maximum height of both pendula. Using this they verified that momentum is conserved, so that Newton's third law holds for the collision forces.

Comment: Are you saying these experiments on glass weren't actually conducted by Newton but by Wren, Wallis & Huygens?

Comment: This is a pendulum experiment. It's difficult to determine who did what. I looked it up and some people think that Wren and Wallis copied from Huygens and Huygens was blocked from publishing until after Wren and Wallis published the copied work. Such controversies happened a lot. There is the famous controversy between Leibniz and Newton about calculus. There is the controversy about Newton's law of gravitation that might actually be Hooke's.

Comment: Newton's third law has many special cases, such as conservation of momentum in collisions, in spring and pulley systems, and in gravity. Perhaps Newton was the first to note that it is a general principle that forces always come in pairs due to an interaction between two objects, and not a property of specific systems.

Comment: Ok, this is getting away from the main point of the question. A lot of what you've mentioned I already know, and isn't news to me. Thanks for the discussion though.

Comment: The main question has been answered. The answer to the question in the title is that you can't do it from first principles because it is easy to imagine universes in which Newton's third law is false, and if you want a set of basic principles you get Lagrangian mechanics + space translation symmetry = momentum conservation = Newton's third law by Noethers theorem. The answer to the question whether your argument is more basic is that your argument only applies to identical particles whereas Newton's third law is general. It's not even clear that it applies there, what about the Lorentz force?

Comment: I'm not sure that you have properly understood the content of the question; for example, you say that neither Kant or I mention the word force; yet Kant says, "if every change of motion has an external cause" where he's implicitly referring to the notion of force. This is roughly Aristotles definition of force. As for going from identical particles to the general - have you come across the notion of induction? And as I've already pointed out Noethers theorem is an outcome of Newtons Mechanics and not a priori. What about the Lorentz force - am I asking about electromagnetism?

Comment: I have properly understood the content of the question, and I have already explained why "change of motion" is not right: change of motion means delta v, whereas the correct statement would refer to delta p (momentum).

Comment: Induction to generalise from the symmetric case to the general case when you've used symmetry in an essential way to derive the symmetric case makes no sense. There is no reason to assume that two non-identical particles would interact in a symmetric way.

Comment: Noethers theorem is not an outcome of Newton's Mechanics. It followed historically, but it does not follow logically. Logically Noethers theorem follows from the principle of least action, which in turn follows logically from quantum mechanics.

Comment: The Lorentz force is a force, and Newton's third law talks about forces. This is a case where you can't apply symmetry even with identical particles, because the particles can be moving in a way that destroys the symmetry, which shows that the argument only applied to identical particles that are also moving in a symmetric way. By the way, everything we observe in daily life except gravity is an electromagnetic phenomenon, including the collision of two balls. All of this is the result of forces acting at a distance.

Comment: Sure the Lorentz force is a force, but the question isn't asking about this. To be honest you're missing the point. Even in the situation you're talking about Newtons laws still applies. By the way, I have a masters in physics and I don't know why you feel it neccessary to tell me stuff I already know about.

Comment: That Newton's law applies is the point, because your argument does not apply and hence cannot be used to argue for Newton's law, only a very special case.

Comment: If you have a masters in physics then you should indeed have known all this, and you should have been able to see that Kant's argument is totally wrong and your argument only applies in the very special case of identical particles moving only in the direction of the line going through both particles. I felt necessary to explain this because you act as if you were not able to see those flaws. Why do that?

Comment: Maybe if you were less arrogant you could see there is some value in Kants argument.

Comment: What value would that be? His argument is fundamentally flawed. This has nothing to do with arrogance. His argument is just wrong.

Comment: I can't help it if you're blind to the argument; and to be honest I'm not interested in arguing or discussion. As I've already said nothing you're said is actually new to me; lets agree to disagree.

Comment: I'm not blind to the argument. I explained in concrete terms why it is wrong. You have not responded to that in any way. In fact, this entire ordeal consists of you claiming that you already know everything I say even though what you say demonstrates that you do not, and you claiming that I'm missing the point, without any explanation whatsoever.

Comment: Speaking of arrogance, you thought you could justify Newton's third law by pure thought, and that somehow all the great physicists including Newton missed this brilliant insight. Your argument could be made in one sentence: "In a symmetric situation the forces are symmetric". Do you really think Newton missed that argument, and therefore relied on experimental evidence? Or maybe Newton understood that his third law is actually far more general than this trivial special case?

Comment: Lets agree to disagree. I'm not really interested in continuing this 'ordeal' any longer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you explain to me how to apply Kant's principles to the following scenario? Suppose two objects A and B, and that B is pushed towards A by some external cause; suppose we neglect gravity and electrical attraction between A and B; according to Newton there is no action and reaction between A and B (until they collide), is there? but according to Kant, there is, isn't there? what is going on?

Is there a consensus that Kant's and Newton's laws are equivalent?

2) As an answer to your question, Feynman derives conservation of momentum (in collisions) from Galilean relativity in [Chapter 10 of the Feynman Lectures](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_10.html#Ch10-S2), and a few simple a posteriori assumptions.

On the other hand he argues that even Galilean relativity (and physics in general) is **not** a priori in [chapter 16](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_16.html):

> Our inability to detect absolute motion is a result of experiment and
>   not a result of plain thought

He then presents an interesting argument to support that statement.

So, is there a consensus among philosophers of science and physicists that Kant's laws of motion are a priori?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your argument; Kant is simply deducing Newton's third law from more basic assumptions - this is what he means by *a priori*.

Comment: There are different senses of *a priori* - it's not meant to be a deduction of 'pure thought'

Comment: Kants term is *synthetic a priori*; I've no idea how Kants ideas are taken by philosophers of science - I haven't looked into it; however Bohm for one did.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to Bohm discussing Kant's laws of motion? Do you understand Kant's laws of motion? can you explain to me the scenario I was trying to figure out?

Comment: I'm not sure even Kant would call his derivation his laws; he's quite careful to call them Newtons laws. Bohm doesn't discuss Kants laws of motion - there's no such thing; what he's interested in is Kantian idealism; it's somewhat implicit in his discussion in *Wholeness and the Implicate Order* - where he mentions Kant by name. comments aren't the place to ask questions - if you want to ask a question that's what the buttons above are for.

Comment: I'm Jewish, and it is well known that we love to answer a question by asking one; anyway I referred you to a beautiful derivation of conservation of momentum, which is related to the third law, from the principle of Galilean relativity, so you should be satisfied!